# Why my projectile(Image object) is not moving? Java Swing

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jpanel, keylistener

I'm trying to make a demo spaceship shooter. Every time i press the space bar I draw a new projectile(`Image`) in the `paintComponent(Graphics g)` method and call a `moveProjectile()` method. The problem is the `moveProjectile()` method seems to be off.

**MyJPanel.java**

```
import java.awt.Cursor;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyAdapter;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseMotionListener;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.Timer;

public class MyJPanel extends JPanel implements ActionListener
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private Timer timer;
    private Image backgroundImage;
    private Image player;
    private int playerX, playerY;
    private int projectileX,projectileY;
    private Image projectileImage;
    private ArrayList<Image> projectiles = new ArrayList<Image>();

    boolean flag = false;

    public MyJPanel(Image backgroundImage, Image player,Image projectileImage)
    {
        this.backgroundImage = backgroundImage;
        this.player = player;
        this.projectileImage = projectileImage;
        this.setLayout(null);

        timer = new Timer(50, this);
        timer.start();

        this.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() // Listens for a keyboard event
        {
            public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) 
            {
                if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_SPACE) // If pressing space - shoot
                {
                    flag = true;
                    moveProjectile();
                }
                repaint();
            }
        });

        // Mouse listener
        this.addMouseMotionListener(new MouseMotionListener()
        {   
            @Override
            public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e)
            {
                playerX = e.getX();
                playerY = e.getY();
            }

            @Override
            public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e)
            {

            }
        });
        hideMouseCursor();

        this.setFocusable(true);
        this.setVisible(true);
    } // End of JPanle constructor

    public void paintComponent(Graphics graphics)
    {
        super.paintComponent(graphics);

        graphics.drawImage(backgroundImage,0,0,this.getWidth(),this.getHeight(),null); // Draw the background
        graphics.drawImage(player,playerX,playerY,null); // Draw the player
        if (flag)
        {
            projectileX = playerX + player.getWidth(null);
            projectileY = playerY + player.getHeight(null) / 2 - 27;
            graphics.drawImage(projectileImage,projectileX,projectileY,null);
        }
    }

    public void moveProjectile()
    {
        while (projectileX < this.getWidth())
        {
            this.projectileX += 2;
            repaint();
        }
    }

    public void  hideMouseCursor() // Hides the mouse cursor
    {
        //Transparent 16 x 16 pixel cursor image.
        BufferedImage cursorbackgroundImgage = new BufferedImage(16, 16, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);

        // Create a new blank cursor.
        Cursor blankCursor = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().createCustomCursor(
                cursorbackgroundImgage, new Point(0, 0), "Blank Cursor");

        // Set the blank cursor to the JPanel.
        this.setCursor(blankCursor);
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent actionEvent) // Without the method and the repaint() the mouse listener will not work 
    {
        repaint();
    }

    public class ProjectileThread extends Thread
    {
        @Override
        public void run()
        {
            projectileX = playerX + player.getWidth(null);
            projectileY = playerY + player.getHeight(null) / 2;

        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("A Game by me");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH); // Making the frame take a full screen

        ImageIcon backgroundImageIcon = new ImageIcon("space_background_2.jpg");
        Image backgroundImgage = backgroundImageIcon.getImage();
        ImageIcon playerImageIcon = new ImageIcon("spaceship_1.png");
        Image playerImage = playerImageIcon.getImage();
        ImageIcon projectileIcon = new ImageIcon("spaceship_projectile_1.png");
        Image projectileImage = projectileIcon.getImage();  

        frame.add(new MyJPanel(backgroundImgage,playerImage,projectileImage));
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
} // End of MyJPanel
```

There some variables and methods i don't use so don't mind them please. The points to notice in the code:

```
if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_SPACE) // If pressing space - shoot
{
    flag = true;
    moveProjectile();
}
repaint();
```

If pressing space -> flag = true which means

```
if (flag)
{
    projectileX = playerX + player.getWidth(null);
    projectileY = playerY + player.getHeight(null) / 2 - 27;
    graphics.drawImage(projectileImage,projectileX,projectileY,null);
}
```

Draw the projectile and move it to the right. The problem is it's never moved to the right. Instead it's following the spaceship which moves by the mouse.

Any suggestions will be very appreciated.

```
public class ProjectileThread extends Thread
{
    public ProjectileThread(int playerX,int playerY)
    {
        projectileX = playerX + player.getWidth(null);
        projectileY = playerY + player.getHeight(null) / 2;
    }
    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        while (projectileX < getWidth())
        {
            projectileX += 2;
        }
    }
}



public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) 
        {
            if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_SPACE) // If pressing space - shoot
            {
                ProjectileThread projectileThread = new ProjectileThread(playerX,playerY);
                projectileThread.start();
            }
            repaint();
        }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your moveProjectile method moves the projectile horizontally by adding 2 to its X coordinate

```
this.projectileX += 2;
```

However, your paint method overwrite this value with your player X coordinate:

```
projectileX = playerX + player.getWidth(null);
```

So everytime you paint your projectile, it's in the same place relative to the player. You need to draw the projectile first using the player coordinates, and then move it without resetting its X coordinate.

You have a thread that should be started when the projectile is fired. So in your handler for the space key, start the thread and pass it the player coordinate. This is your start point. Then in the run method of the thread, move the projectile and wait a bit in a loop.

Comment: I figured that was the problem but i tried initializing the projectile (X,Y) in different places in my code and it was drawn on the top left corner(Probably the default location of the cursor). So where exactly in my code i need to initialize it?

Comment: I've edited my answer. When you press the space key, you initialize the coordinates according to the player's position. Then afterwards you move the projectile independently of the player.

Comment: And when do i draw the projectile?

Comment: I added the Thread code as you said. And the key pressed. Now what about drawing the projectile?

Answer (score 1):

```
while (projectileX < getWidth())
{
    projectileX += 2;
}
```

All this does is set projectile = getWidth() + 1 (or possibly+2).
Similarly, your moveProjectile method has this:

```
while (projectileX < this.getWidth())
{
    this.projectileX += 2;
    repaint();
}
```

Which does the same thing. Note that the repaint() in the body of the loop essentially does nothing, since you block the event thread until the moveProjectile() method returns